# Kial ne “okulvitro” anstataŭ “okulvitroj” se kaj “pantalono” kaj “tondilo” estas singularaj?

Tags: word-difference, plurals, reforms

Logike, se oni portas okulvitrojn, tio kio estas super la nazo estas unuopa, kvankam ĝi enhavas du pecoj da vitro aŭ plasto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Jen okulvitro! ………………………………………………………………………

Comment: Pli valoras unu bild' ol vortoj mil.

Comment: Aha, du okuloj, du okulvitroj.

Comment: Efektive, tio estas **monoklo**. Laux PIV "okulvitro" ne ekzistas en singularo.

Comment: Do, se la mitologia Ciklopo bezonus korektivan lenson, li aĉetus monoklon, kaj se iu alia bezonus lensojn, li aĉetus, eble, duoklon? Tiam, se iu ajn posedus du parojn de okulvitroj, tiu havus du duoklojn, ĉu ne?

Comment: 'monoklo' estas neanalizebla, oni ne povas tiubaze formi "*duoklo*.
@TomasoAlexander pravas, kaj la afero estas pli malsimpla: En la Fundamento "okulvitro", do singularo, havas la celatan signifon, do la pluraligo estas nenecesa, tamen aperas jam en la Dua Libro, do longe antaŭ la Universala Vortaro, kaj m povis trovi tiun uzon en la Tekstaro nur dufoje ĉe Szathmári.

Answer (score 9):

Ĉar estas du vitroj kaj nur unu pantalono kaj nur unu ilo por tondi.

Diversaj lingvoj traktas tiajn aferojn malsame. "Logike" tamen, unu parto de tondilo ne povas tondi kaj sekve ne povas esti tondilo. Pantolono ja havas du krurumojn, sed ĉemizo ja havas du manikojn. Tio tute ne gravas.